# How to read service bus connection string in arm template

Tags: azure, arm, azure-servicebus-topics

what is the best way to read service bus connection string from different resource group in arm template without any hardcoded values?

"connectionString": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('servicebusname'), 'RootManageSharedAccessKey'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString]"

Here the apiversion is hard coded , how can I get it programmatically?

Comment: Can’t you pass the API version as a parameter to your ARM template?

Comment: How do I pass it?

Comment: Just like you’re passing service bus name parameter.

Comment: But does the api version same for different environments? If I hard coded that, will it be different in prod and non prod environments?

Comment: API version has nothing to do with your environments. It’s the version of the Service Bus REST API.

Answer (score 0):

API versions are used to distinguish between different APIs. API versioning is the practice of transparently managing changes to your API. It doesn't matter for prod and non-prod environments at your end as it is specific to the service.
For more details on ARM template for service bus you can refer to [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.servicebus/namespaces/queues?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template). For different API version for service bus what is added/removed you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.servicebus/change-log/namespaces/queues).